# How to remove the "Booting OS" header after selecting an OS in rEFInd?

Tags: boot, uefi, refind

I am currently trying to theme rEFInd, and, following the documentation, I had no problem changing the background banner and icons to fit my needs. However, when selecting a Linux distribution to boot, rEFInd displays an intermediary "Booting OS..." screen in text mode, which stays on for a few seconds, and does not look very good. I am therefore trying to remove this intermediary screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an appropriate option to disable this in this table found in rEFInd documentation ([here](https://rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#adjusting)) : the `use_graphics_for` option, when set to `osx,linux` in `refind.conf` instead of the default `osx` value, disables the "Booting OS..." screen for any linux distributions, keeping the background set with the `banner` option until the OS clears the screen buffer.